# list index out of range when appending data in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in which I have data in three columns and I want to add new rows after checking the data exists then want to add these data in new rows but getting the error `list index out of range`

this is my code

Categories

```
name
apple
banana
potatoes
onion
```

CSV data

```
titles,summaries,terms
apple,,Apple (Fruit)
banana,,Banana (Fruit)
potatoes,,Potato (Vegitable)
onion,,Onion (Vegitable)
```

```
categories = db.table('categories').get()

csv_data = csv.reader(open('categories.csv', "r"))

csv_matched_strings = []
for row in csv_data:
    for category in categories:
        if category.name in row[0]:
            print(row[0] + ': ' + row[2])
            csv_matched_strings.append(category.name)
            List = [row[0],'',row[2]]
            with open('categories.csv', 'a+') as f_object:
                writer_object = writer(f_object)
                writer_object.writerow(List)
                f_object.close()
```

Note: Data is added in the existing CSV file but CSV file writing with a blank line between every loop.

Comment: Please include a minimal copy of your csv file so we can better explain what happened, and provide a new solution

Comment: The only place that seems to be able to cause an `IndexError` is accessing `row` by indices. Can you provide a stack trace? Also code defining `categories`

Comment: What is `categories`? it seems to be an object that you haven't clearly defined

Comment: categories is an object where is coming from database
``categories = db.table('categories').get()``

Comment: @Sorbet categories is an object where from I'm getting name of categories for matching

Comment: Okay, you seem to be handling the open file in a confusing manner. First of all, you open `categories.csv` for the first time (and then never close it), then inside you open the file again and again for each row, appending to the original csv. This makes the file longer and longer until it is finally closed. Consider opening the file once for reading (with a context manager as you did later), then perform the matching, and finally append to it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. How can get rid of this

Comment: What is exactly you want to achieve? What should the line `if category.name in row[0]` check? What needs to be written to the file?

Comment: let me define. What I want. First of all, I'm getting categories' names from the database and checking these name lists with the ``CSV`` titles column if these are matched then I am addinging duplicates in these ``CSV`` files with appending

Comment: ``category.name in a row[0]`` the category.name is the database names list which I'm matching with CSV column ``row[0]`` and getting matched name which appending

Comment: Correct me if I got it wrong. If the first value of a row is found in `categories`, you want to append the row again at the end of the file?

Comment: Yes, Dear, you are right.

Comment: @Sorbet have you understood my problem?

Comment: Yes, Dear, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with the original solution was handling the file. The outer `for` loop wouldn't stop, since the inner for loop was appending line to the working file.

Here, I used a simple list to store what needs to be duplicated. If the file is too large, another option would be to use **a second CSV file** as a buffer and then copy it back at the end.

Also, consider using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) when doing look-ups and maybe learn about how the `in` operator works [here is a post you might find helpful](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-in-basic/).

```
import csv
from csv import writer

# Since OP hasn't provided the class, consider this a substitute
categories = [
    {'name': 'apple'},
    {'name': 'banana'},
    {'name': 'potatoes'},
    {'name': 'onion'},
]

# set of category names created using a set comprehension
cat = {c['name'] for c in categories}

found_rows = []
csv_matched_strings = []

with open('categories.csv', "r") as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f)

    for row in csv_data:
        if row[0] in cat:
            # First value is found in categories
            print(row[0] + ': ' + row[2])
            found_rows.append([row[0], '', row[2]])
            # I left it here since it was there in the original code
            csv_matched_strings.append(row[0])

# categories.csv is now closed.
# We open it again in append mode and proceed to append the duplicates
with open('categories.csv', 'a+') as f:
    writer_object = writer(f)
    for row in found_rows:
        writer_object.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dear Sorbet. You solved my problem. and now is appending fine.

Comment: But one issue is coming which i want to tell you that when appending data then on every loop getting an empty line in ``CSV`` what is the problem with this. Thanks

Comment: Dear, I got it with this function
``writer_object = writer(f, lineterminator='\n')``

Comment: Glad you got your way around it and found my solution helpful, cheers